# Rails: Displaying Only Comments That Belong To A Post That Belong To A Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I am building out a messaging system for my app that is almost exactly how Stackoverflow works. I have two loops running. One for each Post and then inside, one for Comments made for that Post. Right now; it displays All the comments in the entire database and not just for those Posts.

discussion.html.erb

```
<% @projects.posts.each do |post| %>      
  <%= post.content %>
</div>

<% @projects.posts.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.content %>
</div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def discussion    
  @projects = Project.includes(:posts => :comments).find(params[:id])
  @posts = Project.find(params[:id]).posts 
  @comments = Project.find(params[:id]).posts.comments
end
```

Comment: I do have the has_many and belongs_to set correctly on the model files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @projects.posts.each do |post| %>      
  <div>  <!-- Need to open your div -->
    <%= post.content %>
  </div>

  <% post.comments.each do |comment| # Scope to the current post %>
  <div>  <!-- Need to open your div -->
    <%= comment.content %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```